# javascript value pass to php

Tags: php, javascript

Is there a way to pass javascript value to php?

```
if(echo '<script>window.location.href="/mysite"</script>' === "/mysite"){
   $myVal = 1;

}else{
   $myVal = 2;
}
```

This way seems doesn't work

Comment: Can you tell what you want to happen? Now you are just comparing 2 strings, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Use a get variable, `window.location.href="/?site=mysite"` then on php you can test if `$_GET['site']=="mysite"`.

Comment: are you trying to determine the location of the current file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope you can't do it. If you want something like that best and easiest way is using JQuery ajax function http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ which will send request to server with data you want to given script (easiest way - make other .php file?) and if you want something returned, it will be in ajax returned data. Read provided link and you should be good to go.

If you want to know on which site you are currently (as in example) you can use $_SERVER array and get variable which you want from it. List is here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP code executes server-side. JavaScript executes client-side. There's no way for the two to communicate unless you create a web service in PHP that is called from the JavaScript. Unfortunately that won't solve your problem.

If you're trying to set values based on the requested url, you could try:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URL'] === "/mysite"){
    $myVal = 1;
} else {
    $myVal = 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, I used this way. Just wondering if I could make them to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

The code I see in your post shows that you completely misunderstand PHP and Javascript nature.

Send JS var through AJAX request and then work with it in some server-side script.

Answer (score 0):

php is executed on the server side first.

then javascript is executed on the client side. So it's after the php has been rendered.

The only way to send javascript values to php, is using ajax to send an asynchronous call.